# How to access a view present in a fragment's

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a **fragment**   with one **editText**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textViewName"

/>
```

I want to change its text at run time .

How can i access edit Text  so that i can change its text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `onCreateView()`, you can find out particular view by inflating your layout.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myFragmentLayout, container, false);
    EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    return view;
}
```

### Or

you can use `getView()` if you don't want to inflate, it will return root view of the fragment.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
```

Comment: @MahajanGuy you should have marked the 1st answer which has helped you out :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's Say you have a class EditFragment

```
public class EditFragment extends Fragment
{
    private EditText edit;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myFragmentLayout, container, false);
          edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
          return view;
    }
}
```

You can make a getter to access the `EditText` of this `Fragment`

```
public EditText getEditText()
{

    return edit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        EditText e = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

    ....
}
```